# Store big number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to store number around 2147483647 in Oracle table.

What Oracle table field can you recommend as most suitable for this number?

Comment: Do you mean what data type? NUMBER. You can experiment with it: `create table aaa ( x number );` then `insert into aaa values (2147483647)`. Then `select x from aaa` and when you are done, `drop table aaa`. I promise you, it's even much easier than it sounds.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle doc

> NUMBER Datatype The NUMBER datatype stores fixed and floating-point
>   numbers. Numbers of virtually any magnitude can be stored and are
>   guaranteed portable among different systems operating Oracle Database,
>   up to 38 digits of precision.
>
> The following numbers can be stored in a NUMBER column:
>
> Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10-130 to 9.99...9 x 10125 with up
>   to 38 significant digits

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209